# Given $g(m) = \sqrt{m-4}$, solve for $g(m) = 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the algebra for this? I know if we set $\sqrt{m-4} - 2 = 0$, the only number that would make sense is to plug $8$ in for $m$, but how do I show that algebraically?

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{m-4}=2$, so squaring, we have $m-4=4$.

Comment: ... and carefully we verify that indeed $\sqrt{8-4}=2$

Answer (score 0):

By definition for any $x\ge 0$

$$y=\sqrt x\ge 0 \iff y^2=x$$

in this case since we know that $\sqrt{4}=2$, we need $m-4=4$ which leads to the correct unique solution.

Comment: For any $x\ge0$ and any $y\ge0$. The second condition is essential: $(-2)^2=4$, but $-2\ne\sqrt{4}$.

Comment: @egreg Yes of course, I fix that important condition for the definition. Thanks